# DAX expression: create a new table from table reshaping

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to Power BI and perhaps this is a very stupid question.

What I would like to achieve is to create a new table based on the original table by reshaping it, using DAX.

The original table looks like:

```
ID  Start   End
1   Sep 2013    Oct 2013
2   Oct 2013    Jan 2014
3   Oct 2013    Dec 2013
4   Oct 2013    Nov 2013
5   Nov 2013    Dec 2013
6   Nov 2013    Jan 2014
```

The new table will use the values in "Start" and "End" as the row names, and the count of "Start" and "End" in each month-year as the values. This means the expected, reshaped new table looks like:

```
MonthYear   StartCount  EndCount
Sep 2013    1   0
Oct 2013    3   1
Nov 2013    2   1
Dec 2013    0   2
Jan 2014    0   2
```

I would like to learn if you have any idea how to reshape the table using DAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create a calculated table, this should return your expected output:

```
New Table =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE (
            UNION ( VALUES ( Data[Start] ); VALUES ( Data[End] ) );
            Data[Start]
        );
        "Date"; [Start]
    );
    "StartCount"; CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Data ); Data[Start] = EARLIER ( [Date] ) );
    "EndCount"; CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Data ); Data[End] = EARLIER ( [Date] ) )
)
```

With **UNION** and **SUMMARIZE** I am getting the distinct values you have for the dates, using **SELECTCOLUMNS** just for creating the Alias.
With **ADDCOLUMNS** using it to create the scope for the **CALCULATE**s to work on with the use of **EARLIER** for filtering the data.

Comment: This works exactly as expected! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: This is kind of pivoting data, Interesting !!